# Which Eclipse version for Egit?

Tags: java, eclipse, egit

I have `Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers Version: Juno Release` and I work with `Egit` which has `.jsp` `.ejs` `.sql` files which I can't open them with the current version (unlike `.java` which opened with double click in the eclipse editor) .

I work with `windows 7` .

Which eclipse version or any extension tool I need to open them ?

Comment: Can't open them? What do you mean by can't open them? What happens when you double click them?

Comment: You edit still clarifies nothing. In Eclipse when you double click a file, it opens on an editor. For some files (like XMLs) there are special editors. Files not recognized are opened in the default text editor. So, what happens when you double click a .jsp?

Comment: @m0skit0 when I try to open the files I mentioned above , its prompts a windows that asks with which program use inn order to open this file  . What I want is that it automaticly open with the default text editor .

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the file and choose Open With...> Other > Internal Editors and choose text editor to open any file.

Comment: I want to open it with the regular eclipse text editor such as `.java`.

Comment: select Java editor instead then. I think there is also a JSP editor. I wouldn't recommend opening JSPs in Java editor though.